# How far back in time does "recent past" mean in the following sentence when applying for law enforcement?

Tags: expressions

How far back in time does "recent past" mean in the following sentence when applied to law enforcement?

> Have you used Marijuana or any illicit narcotics within the recent past?

Comment: This probably isn't the best place to come for legal advice, dude.

Comment: In this particular case it probably means within the last few weeks. In other contexts it might be the last few days, or the last few months. I doubt if there are any contexts where it might mean the last few hours, but as @simchona says, it could be or years or even decades somtimes.

Answer (score 4):

It may also mean recently enough that we can detect it when you pee in a cup. But it depends on the context.

Comment: In any case, it's in your best interest to *act* as if this is what that means.